# Assigning multiple value in an array after declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, clr

I will really appreciate and remain grateful to him/her who can help me for solving my problem in CLR (Common Language Runtime). It is similar like C/C++.
Generally we use the below method to assign value in array.

```
1. int  values[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
2. Looping.
```

In my program I need to use this assignment after declaration. Like below,

```
int  values[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
values[] = { 10,20,30,40,50,60,700,800,900 };
```

But it is not working.The second statement is erroneous said by compiler.I do not want to use looping. Is there any way to assign array value in second bracket after declaring the array? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: The long and short of it is "you can't do it that way".

Comment: But I need that without looping..@MadScienceDreams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard class `std::array` instead. For example

```
#include <array>

//...


std::array<int, 9> values = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
values = { 10,20,30,40,50,60,700,800,900 };
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>


int main()
{
    std::array<int, 9> values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for ( int x : values ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    values = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 700, 800, 900 }; 

    for ( int x : values ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
10 20 30 40 50 60 700 800 900
```

Though I did no test the program in the CLR environment.

Comment: Thanks for helping me by thinking in a different way. Please don't forget to Upvote the question if you think.I will remain grateful to you for helping me @Vlad from Moscow