# Setting multiple array values after declaration

Tags: arrays, c, embedded

Is there any way to set the values in an array after it has been declared?

```c
unsigned char values[16];
// Some other code to decide what to put into the values array
values = {0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD};
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628720/assigning-multiple-value-in-an-array-after-declaration) solution but it is for a C++ implementation. I'm trying to be efficient on memory and avoid a `memcpy` as well as I don't always need to fill the entire array like in the example above. So far this is the only method that I know works but its very kludgy.

```c
unsigned char values[16];
// Some other code to decide what to put into the values array
values[0] = 0xAA;
values[1] = 0xBB;
values[2] = 0xCC;
values[3] = 0xDD;
```

Comment: `memcpy(values, (int[]){0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD}, 4*sizeof *values);` see https://ideone.com/9ruF7z

Comment: you are efficient when using `memcpy()`... not when avoiding it :)

Comment: @pmg OP's array is an `unsigned char` array, so a `memcpy` from an `int` array won't work.

Comment: My bad @user3386109... but the point is still valid for `unsigned char` as long as you change the type of the unnamed object. Thank you!

Comment: @pmg Yes sorry, that comment was more for the benefit of the OP, who would be disappointed if they tried it without fully understanding it. I agree that your suggestion is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would do:

```
unsigned char* values;
// Some other code to decide what to put into the values array
values = (unsigned char[]) {0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD};
```

Appendix: Note that it really depends on what you need. Since values is not an array anymore in this case.

Comment: This possibly enforces an extra level of indirection though, so this could be less efficient, in case the compiler can't optimize away the `values` variable.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for the hint. I was assuming that any compiler would likely make this to a memcpy, making it equivalent to your answer. Like in the case of, e.g., assigning structs. Maybe I'm confusing or missing something. Could you elaborate what this indirection would be?

Answer (score 0):

Either use `memcpy` or assign each index manually, there is no other sensible solution. You don't *have* to `memcpy` the whole array at once, just restrict it to some indices:

```
memcpy(&values[0], (unsigned char[]){0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD}, 4);
```

where `values[0]` can easily be changed to any `values[i]`. This is also safe as far as alignment is concerned. Note that there should be no benefit in terms of efficiency between this code and assigning all 4 indices manually. Strive to make the code as readable as possible - if you think compound literals are hard to read for example, then stick to what you already have.